# Restrict list view visibility based on custom field value

Tags: list-view

Is it possible to create a new "custom list view" only visible to specific users depending on "custom field value".

Ex: we have custom field (Flag), if it is checked then it needs to be visible to specific group of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. List Views are shared per the Role Hierarchy. You can't use "custom filters" for sharing.

Comment: or by Public Group membership